# Import a table from a user to a table of an other user

Tags: oracle, exp, imp

I am trying to use imp to Import a table from user abdou2 to user abdou1.
I exported my table from abdou2 inside a file dump using:

```
exp abdou2/root file=CLIENTS.dmp tables=CLIENTS
```

Then, I created in abdou1 an exact same Table but empty using:

```
CREATE TABLE imp_CLIENTS AS SELECT * FROM abdou2.CLIENTS WHERE 1=2;
```

And I want to directly by using imp import abdou2.CLIENTS to abdou1.imp_CLIENTS. Both instructions mentioned above worked. Is it possible to do? Thank you

Comment: You can do this in expdp/impdp. WIth exp/imp you can use FROMUSER and TOUSER to import into anothe schema, but it would allow name transforms of table. Data Pump offers REMAP_SCHEMA and REMAP_TABLE options that will do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better working solution was to, indeed, use expdp/impdp.